# how to make emacs' zencoding-mode use single quote insted of double quote

Tags: emacs, emmet

I use single quote when writing html, but zencoding-mode's expanding code use double quote.

I can't find a customize option about this, my zencoding-mode comes from https://github.com/rooney/zencoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `"` is hard-coded into the source, so there's not direct way to customize it. It would be easy to do, so perhaps you could submit a feature request to the maintainer.

In the meantime, it looks like what you need is a modified version of `zencoding-make-html-tag`, replacing all instances of `"\""` with `"'"`. You could add a custom version of the function to your .emacs, with a hook to load it after zencoding. Something like the following might do it:

```
(defun my-zencoding-hook ()
    (zencoding-mode))
(eval-after-load "zencoding-mode"
    '(defun zencoding-make-html-tag ()
       "Insert your modified version of zencoding-make-html-tag here"
       ...))

(add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook 'my-zencoding-hook)
```

Easier but more prone to surprises would be to do a search-and-replace in the source of zencoding-mode.el itself, since it runs from wherever you downloaded it to. This will break whenever you update your version, and might break behaviour for other markup languages, but it's quick and easy.

Comment: thank you, i replace three double quote after \ with single quote in original `zencoding-make-html-tag`, and add a custom hook in my init file, works great.

Comment: @Tyler I modified your answer to use `eval-after-load` so the function overwrite only happens once instead of every time the hook is run.

Comment: @event_jr - thanks. I'll have to look into that, but it sounds like a good idea.