# How to make the tilde overwrite a space in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, coding-style, elisp

I'd like (in TeX-related modes) the tilde key to insert itself as usual if point is on anything (in particular a line end), but if a point is on space, I'd like the tilde to overwrite it.  (This would be a quite useful feature after pasting something into TeX source file.)  I hacked something like this:

```
(defun electric-tie ()
  "Inserts a tilde at point unless the point is at a space
character, in which case it deletes the space first."
  (interactive)
  (while (equal (char-after) 32) (delete-char 1))
  (while (equal (char-before) 32) (delete-char -1))
  (insert "~"))

(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key "~" 'electric-tie)))
```

My questions are simple: is it correct (it seems to work) and can it be done better?  (I assume that if the answer to the first question is in the affirmative, the latter is a question of style.)

Comment: If it works, it is good. Really. It is the credo of the Emacs user. Unless you are writing a new general purpose package.

Comment: Thanks - but I'd like not only to have it working, but to learn something.  Maybe there's a better way to do it?  Maybe I'm using some high-level, `(interactive)` function when I should use something low-level - or *vice versa*?  Maybe I'm using `equal` but it is customary to use `eq` in similar contexts?  Maybe I should `(self-insert)` instead of `(insert "~")`?

Comment: HAH!  That credo is why so many questions here about Emacs are self inflicted gunshot wounds.  @mbork should be commended for trying to understand canonical solutions.

Comment: (I already noticed that it would be better if I took care for more than one space, and ones before as well as after point - question edited.)

Comment: @event_jr: thanks;).  I skimmed through a few of your answers, and it confirmed that my question is not nonsensical; what if, e.g., some functions I use push mark or something like that?  (I believe they don't, this is just an example.)  What's more: I'd like to write about this little function on my blog, and I don't want to spread bad practices;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some points:

1. Instead of `32` use `?`  (question-mark space) to express character literal.
2. Instead of defining keys in the major-mode hooks, do it in an `eval-after-load` block.  The difference is that major-mode hook runs every time you use the major-mode, but there is only one keymap per major-mode.  So there is no point in repeatedly redefining a key in it.

   see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8139587/903943
3. It looks like this command should not take a numeric argument, but it's worth understanding interactive specs to know how other commands you write can be made to be more flexible by taking numeric arguments into consideration.

One more note about your new modifications:

Your way to clear spaces around point is not wrong, but I'd do this:

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (skip-chars-forward " ")
  (delete-region (point) (+ (point) (skip-chars-backward " "))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I did a bit of digging; isn't `?\s` even better as a representation of space character?

Comment: I'm not sure which way is preferred, they both evaluate to 32.

Comment: Well, `?\s` seems to have one advantage: it's more easily visible than `? `

Comment: Hi, I looked into the `eval-after-load` thing; is that really better?  I mean, it seems to depend on the filename, that is, actual *implementation* of the `TeX-mode`; what's more, my solution sets the binding of `~` only in TeX-mode, and I'm not sure how to achieve a similar effect with `eval-after-load`.

Comment: `(eval-after-load 'tex-mode (define-key tex-mode-map ...))`

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, it's better to use a "character" literal than a number literal.  You have the choice between `?` , `?\` , and `?\s` where the last one is only supported since Emacs-22 but is otherwise the recommended way, since it's (as you say) "more easily visible" and also there' no risk that the space char will be turned into something else (or removed) by things like fill-paragraph or whitespace trimming.

You can indeed use `eq` instead of `equal`, but the difference is not important.

Finally, I'd call `(call-interactively 'self-insert-command)` rather than insert by hand, but the difference is not that important (e.g. it'll let you insert 3 tildes with `C-u ~`).